# Selenium WebDriver - Unable to handle alerts that appear on page load

Tags: java, selenium, alert

I have the following scenario to automate:

1. Navigate to the Application URL
2. Click a Button called ***Open New Window***
3. The app opens a new window, which has an alert that appears on page load.
4. Switch to new window and accept / dismiss the alert
5. Proceed with rest of the automation

We have a problem in **Step 4**. When we switch to the new window and try to execute `driver.switchTo().alert().accept()`, we get `NoAlertPresentException`, even though we can see the alert.

Below is our code (extracted into a single class for simplicity).

**Edited**: Based on Mithilesh Indurkar's suggestions (Added implicit waits for new window and alert), also added check to validate against parent window handle

```
@Slf4j
public class AlertTest {
    
    private static final String GECKO_DRIVER_PATH = "path\to\geckodriver.exe";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        // Launch browser
        log.info("Launching Browser");
        WebDriver driver = launchBrowser();
        String strParentWindowHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();
        // Navigate to the App
        log.info("Navigating to app");
        driver.get("http://localhost:5500");
        
        //Here's where the browser opens a new window
        driver.findElement(By.id("btnNewWindow")).click();
        
        
        // Switch to new window
        log.info("Switching to new window");
        boolean windowSwitched = switchToNewWindow(driver, strParentWindowHandle);
        if(!windowSwitched) {
            log.error("Error --> Switch to new window failed. Script is aborting...");
            close(driver);
            return;
        }
        
       try {
           // Wait for alert
           WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
           wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
           
           log.info("Alert is present");
       } catch(TimeoutException e) {
           log.error("Timed out (30 seconds) waiting for alert to be present");
           log.error("Script is aborting...");
           close(driver);
           return;
       }
        
        // Handle alert
        boolean alertHandledSuccessfully = false;
        try {
            Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
            String alertText = alert.getText();
            log.info("Alert handled --> {}", alertText);
            alertHandledSuccessfully = true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Error handling alert", e);
        }
        
        if(alertHandledSuccessfully) {
            // Click the button
            log.info("Clicking button");
            driver.findElement(By.id("btn")).click();
        }else {
            log.error("Error --> Could not handle alert on load");
        }
        
        
        // Close the browser
        log.info("Closing...");
        close(driver);
    }

    private static WebDriver launchBrowser() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", GECKO_DRIVER_PATH);

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        
        return driver;
    }

    private static boolean switchToNewWindow(WebDriver driver, String strParentWindowHandle) {
        
        try {
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.numberOfWindowsToBe(2));
            log.info("No. Of windows is now 2");
        } catch(TimeoutException e) {
            log.error("Error --> Timed out (10 seconds) while waiting for second window to be present");
            return false;
        }
        
        //Added/modified by Mithilesh
        String[] windowHandlesArray = driver.getWindowHandles().toArray(new String[] {});
        String strNewWindowHandle = "";
        for(int intHandleLoopCounter = 0; intHandleLoopCounter <windowHandlesArray.length; intHandleLoopCounter++)
        {
            strNewWindowHandle = windowHandlesArray[intHandleLoopCounter];
            if(strNewWindowHandle.equalsIgnoreCase(strParentWindowHandle) == false)
            {
                driver.switchTo().window(strNewWindowHandle);
                log.info("Switched to window with handle {}", strNewWindowHandle);
                return true;

            }
            else if(intHandleLoopCounter==windowHandlesArray.length)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        
        return false;
    }
    
    private static void close(WebDriver driver) {
        if(driver == null) return;
        driver.close();
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Now, when we try to handle the alert that appears when the new window is being loaded, we get the following exception:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoAlertPresentException: 
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'YCSLAP0010', ip: '172.22.0.1', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_231'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: firefox, browserVersion: 88.0, javascriptEnabled: true, moz:accessibilityChecks: false, moz:buildID: 20210415204500, moz:geckodriverVersion: 0.29.0, moz:headless: false, moz:processID: 17472, moz:profile: C:\Users\s.sriram\AppData\L..., moz:shutdownTimeout: 60000, moz:useNonSpecCompliantPointerOrigin: false, moz:webdriverClick: true, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, platformVersion: 10.0, rotatable: false, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify}
Session ID: 531336cf-f8d3-429a-98d9-555a40c3f7cd
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:609)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver$RemoteTargetLocator.alert(RemoteWebDriver.java:932)
    at com.yethi.agent.wsresponse.util.AlertTest.main(AlertTest.java:36)
```

The problem summary is as follows:

*We are getting a NoAlertPresentException while trying to handle an alert that appears during page load, especially when the page is loaded in a new window.*

The below HTML snippets help you simulate the app's screen(s)

**index.html** - This is assumed to be the landing page of the app

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Alert Simulation</title>
    <script>
      function openNewWindow() {
        window.open("page.html", "_blank", "width=300, height=300");
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form name="loginForm" action="#" method="POST">
      <div>
        <label for="username">User name: </label>
        <input type="text" id="username" name="username" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="password">Password: </label>
        <input id="password" type="password" name="password" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <button type="button" id="btnLogin" onClick="showAlert();">
          Login
        </button>
        <button type="button" id="btnNewWindow" onClick="openNewWindow();">
          Open New Window
        </button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

**page.html** - This opens in a new window, with an alert onLoad.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <script>
      function showAlert(alertText) {
        alert(alertText ? alertText : "Page Loaded!");
      }

      function onButtonClick() {
        showAlert("Button Clicked");
        document.querySelector("#output").innerText = "Button clicked!";
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="showAlert();">
    <h1>This page opens in a new window with an alert onload</h1>
    <button type="button" id="btn" onclick="onButtonClick();">Click Me</button>
    <p id="output"></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a wait before the code that uses the alert, to make sure it has appeared when you try to interact with it?

Comment: Yes. We tried both WebDriverWait, as well as an arbitrary Thread.sleep, but in vain.

Comment: Switch to windowhandles won't work. The alert is not a browser tab or browser window. Add `boolean isDialogPresent(WebDriver driver) {
    IAlert alert = ExpectedConditions.AlertIsPresent().Invoke(driver);
    return (alert != null);
}` to your code and debug it.

Comment: I think you missed a point. The alert appears on a page that in turn opens in a new window. We need to first switch to a new window, and then handle the alert.

Comment: Hi, 

I am sure you must have tried various things but I need to know the below before fully understnading the problem.

1. Have you kept a wait before checking the appearance of the second window? ==> https://codoid.com/wait-for-webdriver-windows-count/#:~:text=NumberOfWindowsToBe%20is%20a%20new%20method,with%20actual%20WebDriver%20windows%20count.

2. Have you given webdriverwait expected condition to wait for the alert?

3. From your methods, **switchToNewWindow**, which text gets printed? does it print anything at all ?

Comment: The answer to Question 3: The console prints "Switched to window with handle xxx". As for questions 1 and 2, we modified the code with WebDriverWait. While the wait for number of windows to be 2 succeeded, the wait for alert to be present failed with a TimeoutException (went till 30 seconds of timeout, and I could see the alert on the page).  I have edited this question with the updated code. Please take a look.

Comment: getWindowHandles() method returns a set. **A 'set' is not an ordered collection**. There is no guarantee that the first opened window handle will be at 0th position and so on. What you should do is, before opening new window, you should note the handle of the parent window, iterate the set/array to find the handle which is NOT equal to the parent window handle and then switch to that window. 



Let me know if it works or if you still need some more details.

Comment: driver.switchTo().window(windowHandlesArray[1]); // this does not guarantee that the 2nd window handle will be used. Even the parent window handle can be present at the second array element as the set is not an ordered collection. You need to put a loop in the array to know which window handle is NOT the parent window handle.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to my comments above, I am typing a solution which could be further fitted into  your solution

**Get the parent window handle just after the launch of the browser.**

```
// Launch browser
            log.info("Launching Browser");
            WebDriver driver = launchBrowser();
            //Added by Mithilesh
            String strParentWindowHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();
```

**This is how switching should be called**

```
// Switch to new window
            log.info("Switching to new window");
            boolean windowSwitched = switchToNewWindow(driver, strParentWindowHandle); //Modified by Mithilesh
            if(!windowSwitched) {
                log.error("Error --> Switch to new window failed. Script is aborting...");
                close(driver);
                return;
            }
```

**This should be your switching method implementation**

```
private static boolean switchToNewWindow(WebDriver driver, String strParentWindowHandle) {
            
            try {
                WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
                wait.until(ExpectedConditions.numberOfWindowsToBe(2));
                log.info("No. Of windows is now 2");
            } catch(TimeoutException e) {
                log.error("Error --> Timed out (10 seconds) while waiting for second window to be present");
                return false;
            }
            
            //Added/modified by Mithilesh
            String[] windowHandlesArray = driver.getWindowHandles().toArray(new String[] {});
            String strNewWindowHandle = "";
            for(int intHandleLoopCounter = 0; intHandleLoopCounter <windowHandlesArray.length; intHandleLoopCounter++)
            {
                strNewWindowHandle = windowHandlesArray[intHandleLoopCounter];
                if(strNewWindowHandle.equalsIgnoreCase(strParentWindowHandle) == false)
                {
                    driver.switchTo().window(strNewWindowHandle);
                    return true;

                }
                else if(intHandleLoopCounter==windowHandlesArray.length)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            
            
        }
```

This looping is required because set is not an ordered collection and does not guarantee that the 2nd window handle will be at 2nd position in the array. Let me know if it works.

Also, You are incorrectly handling the popup. The popup should be handled the follwing ways.

1. accept()
2. dismiss()
3. getText()
4. sendKeys()

in your case, `driver.switchTo().alert().accept()` should be used instead of finding the button on the popup. You cannot click a popup button as a web element like any other web element.

Comment: Hi Mithilesh, tried this approach. Able to switch to the new window, but the WebDriverWait for the alert to be present still times out after 30 seconds. I can however see the alert present on the page.

Comment: OK. This is strange. Doesn't look like a normal alert to me. Would you be able to confirm if the alert generated by your HTML snippet is the same as the one you are getting. If possible, you could post a screenshot of the alert

Comment: I'll arrange for a snapshot. Meanwhile, I'd like to tell you that all along, I have been testing the snippet I've pasted in the question, and it doesn't work. Can you confirm if you can successfully handle the alert in the html snippet I have above? If yes, then there's something definitely wrong with what I am doing..

Comment: @Sriram Sridharan I've tried to run the HTML snippet, it runs fine

Page Loaded!
Button Clicked
PASSED: setUp

===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================

Comment: @YaDavMaNish Can you give me your code snippet? I can try the same locally..

Comment: @SriramSridharan, I have tried the click with your code as well as mine. When it is opened in first window, the click has no problem but when it is done through open new window button from first it gives problems. This is because when the second window is opened the *loading* never stops until you click on the popup. If you click OK manually, the script progresses. 

The only solution is to stop the loading of page progrmmatically(not possible manually tried), your script will work normally.

Comment: Yes @MithileshIndurkar that is the precise problem. The developers of the app say that is not an option. We're struggling to find alternatives..

Comment: @Sriram Sridharan can you just try with the pageLoadStretegy as NONE so that it will not download the images and other resources and won't take a lot of time to load the page have tried this approach? 

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
  options.setPageLoadStrategy(PageLoadStrategy.NONE);
                 options.setPageLoadStrategy(PageLoadStrategy.EAGER);

Answer (score 0):

**I've just executed the above html snippet with the below lines of code,
Hope this would help you**

```
public static void acceptAlert() {
new WebDriverWait(driver,10)
.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent())
.accept();}

public static String getTextFromAlert() {
String str = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.
alertIsPresent()).getText();
return str;}

@Test
public static void setUp() {
WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67481982/selenium- 
      webdriver-unable-to-handle-alerts-that-appear-on-page-load");
new WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(ExpectedConditions.
elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Accept all 
cookies')]"))).click();
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath
("((//button[@class='s-btn s-btn__primary'])[2]/span[2])"));
    
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript
("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
element.click();
System.out.println(getTextFromAlert());
acceptAlert();}

[https://imgur.com/Xy2jhQr][1]
```